# Why are private members/methods defined in the interface?

Tags: c++, oop

I've always been confused by the fact that most OOP languages (or rather, C++) make you define private methods/members in the interface (by interface I mean the class declaration - seems like I was confused). Isn't this showing the implementation details of the class and going against the idea of encapsulation?

Is there a good reason for this that I've been missing?

Comment: I actually never understood this either, personally I would like to see a good answer to this.

Comment: When you say "most OOP languages", which ones do you mean? In Java and in C#, it is not true. In c++ (your tag), there is no concept of interface, it only has classes, right?

Comment: @Moritz “interface” in OP’s text doesn’t mean an empty, abstract base class; it simply means the publicly viewable part of a class. That said, it’s true that most language do *not* handle it like this. C++ must be one of the only, actually.

Comment: Surely if methods were declared outside the class declaration, they could be declared anywhere. It then follows that there is no such thing as 'private'?

Comment: @Keith Well for starters they might be declared only in the compilation unit that defines the object. In fact, that’s what the PIMPL idiom does, and it’s the only way by which C, for instance, provides information hiding at all.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph. Agreed, the PIMPL idiom is a good solution to the problem. So, really protection is passed back to the user to manage, rather that being done by the language. Hence my problem with "compilation unit that defines the object" means. The class declaration is typically defined in a header file; this means that you can "define" the "object" (class) in multiple translation units. When the class declaration determines needs to be defined, the ODR rule then ensures that we have a well defined class. If we could add 'private' stuff at will, what then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For C++ it's an implementation issue.

The C++ compiler must be able to generate code that uses a class by only seeing the class declaration and not the implementation. One very important thing that is needed by the compiler is the size of an instance of the class because among other things C++ handles sub-objects in objects by embedding and not by storing a reference to a separate object. To be able to build an object (e.g. `struct X { Y y; Z z; }`) the size of all sub-objects (e.g. `Y` and `Z`) must be known in advance.

A workaround for this problem is to use [the "pimpl" pattern (also named the "compiler firewall" pattern)](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm) that allows you to keep all internal details hidden from the users of a class. This unfortunately carries some runtime extra cost with it but most the time it's a negligible one. With this approach the public object will always have the size of a pointer and all data in the instance will be accessed using an extra indirection... the advantage is that you can add private data members and users of the class don't need to be recompiled (and if your class is for example in a DLL this allows to maintain even binary compatibility).

Being able to declare just private methods (no data) in the implementation part would have been possible without any added complexity on the compiler, but C++ designer thought it was better to keep one single declaration for a class instead.

Actually even just adding a private method may affect the size of the a class instance in many implementations (e.g. if the private method is the only virtual one in the class).

Comment: and for templates compiler needs to see complete class definition (implementation), not just its declaration

Comment: The "copy" part I don't understand. A compiler should be able to see the declaration of the copy ctor, and leave it to the linker to match the copy ctor call and copy ctor definition. (Of course, it does matter when you put variables on the stack, but that's the same problem regardless of the precise ctor called)

Comment: @MSalters: In C++ if an instance of X contains an instance of Y as member the subobject is phisically allocated inside the other object. So you cannot use Y as a member when declaring X unless Y size is known. In other languages containment is always done using pointers so the size doesn't matter (i.e. for X to contain Y there's no need to know the size of Y because what is stored is just a pointer to a separate instance of Y).

Comment: @6502: Of course. Again, that applies equally to any form of construction; my question is what makes _copy_ special? (And there's no reason why a language _has_ to use shallow copies even when members are stored as pointers. Either choice is possible)

Comment: @MSalters: If you use pointers you can do both ways. But C++ doesn't use pointers so `struct X { Y a; Z b; };` needs to allocate subobjects inside the `X` object and to do that and generate code accessing `a` and `b` needs to know how big those objects are. This approach is mandatory in C++ (consider also `union`) and therefore subobject size must be known.

Comment: @6502: Still agreeing with you the whole way. But I still don't see why "C++ uses copy semantic" is the **cause** of this. Logically, if A allows not-B, then A does not cause B. Copy semantics allow members-as-pointers, therefore copy semantics do not cause member-embedding.

Comment: MSalters: I finally understand what you are saying and I completely agree. I will try to find a better wording...

Answer (score 9):

C++ is the only language that I know which does this; notably, there are several functional languages which strictly separate the declaration of public and private interfaces. And notice that C++ makes a difference between *declaring* and *defining*: you only need to *declare* private functions in the interface, not *define* them.

For member variables as well as virtual functions, there is a simple technical reason: they influence the physical layout of the class. Since this layout needs to be identical across translation units, all units need to know the layout – and hence the physical makeup of the class.

I suspect that you also need to declare non-virtual functions publicly in C++ just to keep it consistent: otherwise, you’d have to declare different functions in different places, depending on whether or not they are public and/or virtual.

You *can* circumvent this restriction by using the [handle-body idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl) (also known by its cosmetically less appealing name “PIMPL”) but this adds its own complexity to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are two senses, in which the word interface is used in C++: an OOP interface and a type declaration.

An OOP interface is used for encapsulation and polymorphism. In C++, it is usually implemented with pure abstract classes. The [PIMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idiom is also used for encapsulation. In either case, the consumer is shown only the type's public members and accesses the private implementation through an indirection layer. Java and C# support explicit interfaces and both restrict their members to public access.

Type declarations are required in C++ due to its linking model. A type's declaration is not its interface in the OOP sense, but because a type's declaration has to be included before use, decoupling the implementation becomes more desirable. In order to achieve this, we use OOP interfaces, as described above. There would be no need to hide private implementation details from a type's declaration, if only C++ supported modules. [Module support](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2073.pdf) was proposed for C++11, but due to time constraints set to be included in a future TR.

Comment: Just because C# has the keyword `interface` doesn't mean it's conceptually any difference.  A class' interface is what is visible to clients of the code, the semantic implementation is irrelevant.

Comment: There is an interface that is "what the client sees" and there is the OOP interface. These are separate things. Encapsulation has to do with the latter and in C++ it is usually achieved with abstract classes.

Comment: @Don “Encapsulation has to do with the latter” – no, wrong. See my comments below K-ballo’s answer, or the relevant Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Don The arguments are below the other answer, where i have explicitly directed you. I don’t really want to repeat them all.

Comment: @Konrad, expanded the answer, especially to address your argument for type declaration encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

In the particular case of C++, one reason is that the declaration of all virtual functions -be them public or private-, is needed in order to generate the virtual pointer table. Probably the same reason applies to other languages as well.

This does not go against the idea of encapsulation, private methods/members are not part of the *PUBLIC* interface so the data remains encapsulated. Besides, public/private modifiers enforce only visibility.

Comment: The reason you mention is correct. But you are incorrect in stating that this doesn’t go against the idea of encapsulation. In fact, this breaks information hiding (and hence encapsulation) big time. In particular, it makes it necessary to recompile the client code every time you change the signature of private functions in a class.

Comment: I would consider that the information remains hidden. Being able to 'see' a declaration doesn't give you access to it, and since you can only manipulate it through the public interface it remains encapsulated. However, its true that recompilation is necesary even when the public interface hasn't changed, I must give you that. My point of view is pure philosophical here, I consider that to be a limitation of current implementations.

Comment: This isn’t what encapsulation means. It’s not about keeping secrets (at least that’s not the usual and most important purpose), it’s about keeping clients isolated from local changes.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, in a programming language encapsulation is used to refer to: A language mechanism for restricting access to some of the object's components. A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data.

Comment: You are citing the wrong part of the article. Under “As information hiding mechanism” you will find a relevant definition.

Comment: I fail to see how that changes things. Let me check with my copy of Meyer's OOSC and I will get back to you. However, I would still consider that recompilation -as breaking isolation from changes- is a limitation of current implementations, and not the result of private members/methods being defined in the class definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3262/discussion-between-konrad-rudolph-and-k-ballo) – I’ve cited the relevant passages from Wikipedia there.

Comment: vtable argument doesn't really hold; that's an implementation detail. You'd trivially solve it with two vtables (public/private), or even the convention that private methods are at negative offsets.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tricks to solve that problem in C++.

You can use [factory pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1) to hide the private members and methods to users.
What you need is to create a `abstract class` as your API or interface, than implement your class in subclass and declare all your private members there, in this way your users won't see your private members and implementations.

Answer (score -1):

How do you get such a conclusion? I found no OOP languages that makes me do so. For C++, the reason people define methods in interface is for inlining purpose. For members, well that's because you can't define it anywhere else, and it applies to all visibilities, not just private.

Comment: -1: the question is not about defining methods in header file